# How to re-enable read ahead (prefetch) feature in SQL Server after disabling it?

Tags: sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server, I've disabled the read ahead (prefetch) feature using

```
    DBCC TRACEON(652,-1)
```

But does anyone know how to enable the read ahead feature?

Before I disabled the read ahead, using

```
    set statistics io on
```

I get this result:

```
    Scan count 1, logical reads 529, physical reads 4, read-ahead reads 1192
```

Now after disabling read ahead using the above DBCC query, I get this:

```
    Scan count 1, logical reads 44, physical reads 19, read-ahead reads 0
```

I'd like to be able to disable/enable the prefetch feature freely so I could compare among different queries. I googled everywhere but didn't find an answer for that... Anyone knows how to re-enable it? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All you need do is turn the trace flag off globally:

```
DBCC TRACEOFF (652, -1);
```

**A service restart is not required**.

To control read-ahead for the current session only, simply omit the `-1`.

```
DBCC TRACEON (652);
...
...tests
....
DBCC TRACEOFF (652);
```

This trace flag is only [minimally documented](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/920093), so for anything more than educational purposes on an isolated test system, it makes sense to contact Microsoft Support for advice.

Note: [`QUERYTRACEON`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2801413) is not effective for trace flag 652.